# I want to send the state from a component to another component to render it, how to do it without Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to do a search input text in a `NavBar` component and send the results array to be rendered in another component. I can change the state in the `Navbar` component, but I do not know how to assign the results to the results array in the `Search` component.

**NavBar Component:**

```
import './NavBar.css';
import Search from '../Search/searchMovies';

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.submitSearch = this.submitSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleSearchInput = this.handleSearchInput.bind(this);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
            searchText: "",
            searchResults: [],
            isLoaded: false
        };
    }

    handleSearchInput(e) {
        this.setState({searchText:e.target.value});
    }

    submitSearch = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=api&language=en-US&query=${this.state.searchText}&page=1&include_adult=false`)
            .then(movies => movies.json())
            .then(({results}) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    searchResults: results
                });
            });
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className='Nav' color="" dark  expand="md">
                    <NavbarBrand  className='logo'id="logo"href="/">
                        <img alt='logo' src=''></img>
                    </NavbarBrand>
                    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                        <Nav className="ml-auto " navbar>
                            <NavItem className="searchInput">
                                <input
                                    placeholder="Search for movies..."
                                    ref={input => this.search = input}
                                    onChange={this.handleSearchInput}
                                />
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink href='/results' >
                                    <Button color="danger" size="lg" onClick={this.submitSearch}>Search</Button>
                                </NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                    </Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Search Component:**

```
import NavBar from '../Navigation/NavBar'

export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            results: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }       
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({results: this.props.results})
    }

    render() {    
        var {isLoaded, results} = this.state
        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div> .... Loading</div>
        } else if(results.length === 0) {
            return <div>Your search - { NavBar.props.results } - did not match any movies.
            Suggestions:
            Make sure that all words are spelled correctly.</div>;
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>Your Search Results!</h3>
                    <Row>
                        { this.props.results.map(Movie => (
                            <Col  sm="3">
                                <Card key={Movie.id} className='Top_Rated' body>
                                    <CardImg top width="100%" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200${Movie.poster_path}`} alt=""/>
                                    <CardTitle className='title' >{Movie.title}</CardTitle>
                                    <CardText className='Text'>Rating:{Movie.vote_average}</CardText>
                                    <Link to={'/movie/' + Movie.id } >
                                        <Button color="danger">Visit</Button>{' '}
                                    </Link>
                                </Card>
                            </Col>
                        ))}
                    </Row>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The API works well and the results array in the `NavBar` component is updated, but I do not know how to send this array to the other component to be rendered.

Comment: Is the `Search` component a child (or grand-child) of the `NavBar` component? You have shown the code of both components, but you have not explained what is the place of these components in the component tree.

Comment: Could you post the file tree and component structure, please?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your query state in the `Search` component, you can pass the state and the state update function down to the NavBar with props. This way you will ensure that the search text of both components are the same.

So you would pass down the query state and the function to update it.

Comment: I have the query state in the Search component but it is empty , I have searchText state in another component I want to make the query state same as the searchText state form another component how to do it?

Comment: Is the one component rendering the other, or are they just independent and need the same state?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is **Redux** https://redux.js.org/

Redux allows you to mantain state across your whole application and the comunication between isolated components that share functionalities.

This is pretty much redux in a nutshell https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/06/an-introduction-to-redux/

Comment: I am not using Redux from the beginning that's why I want another way to change the state from NavBar component and update the Search Component with the text

Comment: There are more fundamental problems with the OP's code that will not be solved with Redux. The OP needs to learn more about how to use components, props, and state before Redux will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing `this.state.searchText` to the `Search` component here:

```
<Search query={this.state.searchText}></Search>
```

in `class Search`, you access it as `this.props.query` since it is passed as a prop. You don't need `this.state.query` in `class Search` at all.

Comment: I change my code from this.state.query to this.props.query but it is not working I think the text is not passed from NavBar to the Search component the query state is not updated by this 
Can you suggest any solution?
`<Search query={this.state.searchText}></Search>`

Comment: @Hazem That does in fact pass the text to the `<Search>` component. Is that component actually rendered? Where in your code do you call `submitSearch()`? In fact, why is `Search` a component at all? Does it render any UI elements? If its sole purpose is to make a HTTP request, then you only need a function to do that. You don't need a component.

Comment: Yes it renders the results so I need the Component , I call SubmitSearch in the NavBar component where I have the search text field I then send the text by `<Search query={this.state.searchText}></Search>` , but when I try to `console.log(this.props.query)` in my Search component it console the result and disappears in a second maybe that is why the fetch is not  working?

Comment: @Hazem You need to add your `render()` methods for both `NavBar` and `Search` for us to help further.

Comment: Sure I will add it now

Comment: I edited my question with the Renders please advise me how to fix it

Comment: @Hazem You are using `submitSearch()` as a `onClick` handler for one of the `Button` components. This executes the function when the user clicks the button but does not render the component. You need to rethink your design here. `submitSearch()` should make the HTTP request instead of doing it in `Search.componentDidMount()`. `Search` should be renamed `SearchResult` and only render the result. You then render it directly from the `NavBar.result()` method.

Comment: Do you mean to delete my search component and do all the work in the NavBar? I updated my code with this .. 
    `submitSearch = () =>(
      <div>
      <NavLink href="/results">
      </NavLink>
      {fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=api&language=en-US&query=${this.state.searchText}&page=1&include_adult=false`).then(movies=>movies.json()).then(({results}) => { this.setState({ isLoaded: true, results: results }
       )})}
      </div>
    )`

how can I render my results now??

Comment: @Hazem I mean that `submitSearch()` should call `fetch()` directly. It should not have any JSX in it at all. Think of it this way: what should happen when the user clicks on the button? I think the answer is that your app needs to make an HTTP request. That's it. It doesn't immediately render anything. That happens when the result comes back from the request, not immediately when the user clicks the button.

Comment: It is not working !! I am really sorry for asking too much but I can't understand how to do it , I make it fetch in the `submitSearch()` and added a state `results:[]` in the NavBar component now I have the same problem I need to render the results array in another component how to pass it ?

Comment: @Hazem You pass it as a prop to the other component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204654/discussion-between-hazem-and-code-apprentice).

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the organization of your components in the component-tree. I'll give you three common solutions using the same components, but in each one, they will be organized in a different way. I will use a `Search` component that will contain an `input` to make the search and a `Display` component that will show the results of the search in different rows. You can identify the `Search` component by the red border and the `Display` component by the green one.

> I'll use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) in the examples because it is easier for me to create the snippets using functional components, but they are not necessary, just observe the organization and how the properties are passed between the components.

1 - If the `Display` component is a child of the `Search` component. This is the most common approach, if it is possible, you should use it. Just store the results of the query in the state of the `Search` component and send it to the child component (`Display`) through its props:

```js
const Results = (props) => {
  const rows = props.results.map((f, i) => (<div key={i} className="row">{ f.title }</div>));
  return (
    <div className="results">
      { rows }
    </div>
  );
};

const Search = (props) => {
  const [ results, setResults ] = React.useState([]);
  const searchAlbum = (e) => {
    const query = e.currentTarget.value;    
    if (query) {
      const filtered = props.albums.filter(a => a.title.indexOf(query) >= 0);
      setResults(filtered);
    } else {
      setResults([]);
    } 
  };
  return (    
    <div className="search">
      <input type="text" onChange={ searchAlbum } placeholder="Search" />
      <Results results={results} />
    </div>
  );
};

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(json => {  
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Search albums={json} />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );  
  });
```

```css
.search {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.results {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

2 - If the `Display` component is a sibling of the `Search` component. This is also a common approach. In this case, you should have a parent component that contains both components, it should receive the query from the `Search` component, store it in its state, and send it to the `Display` component through its props:

```js
const Results = (props) => {
  const rows = props.results.map((f, i) => (<div key={i} className="row">{ f.title }</div>));
  return (
    <div className="results">
      { rows }
    </div>
  );
};

const Search = (props) => {
  const searchAlbum = (e) => {
    const query = e.currentTarget.value;    
    if (props.onSearch && typeof props.onSearch === "function") {
      props.onSearch(query);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <input type="text" onChange={ searchAlbum } placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = (props) => {
  const [ results, setResults ] = React.useState([]);
  const search = (query) => {
    if (query) {
      const filtered = props.albums.filter(a => a.title.indexOf(query) >= 0);
      setResults(filtered);
    } else {
      setResults([]);
    } 
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Search albums={props.albums} onSearch={search} />
      <Results results={results} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(json => {  
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App albums={json} />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );  
  });
```

```css
.search {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.results {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

3 - If the components are too distant from each other, and this makes really difficult to send the data from one to the other. In this case, the use of a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is very helpful, but you should use it if the data needs to be shared by multiple components or due to the design it is really impossible to use one of the previous approaches. If you can change the organization of the components to achieve one of the previous approaches, I would recommend you to do that instead of using a `Context`:

```js
const ResultsContext = React.createContext([]);

const Container = (props) => {
   return (
    <div className="container">
      { props.children }
    </div>
   );
};

const Results = () => {
  const results = React.useContext(ResultsContext);
  const rows = results.map((f, i) => (<div key={i} className="row">{ f.title }</div>));
  return (
    <div className="results">
      { rows }
    </div>
  );
};

const Search = (props) => {
  const searchAlbum = (e) => {
    const query = e.currentTarget.value;    
    if (props.onSearch && typeof props.onSearch === "function") {
      props.onSearch(query);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <input type="text" onChange={ searchAlbum } placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = (props) => {
  const [ results, setResults ] = React.useState([]);
  const search = (query) => {
    if (query) {
      const filtered = props.albums.filter(a => a.title.indexOf(query) >= 0);
      setResults(filtered);
    } else {
      setResults([]);
    } 
  };
  return (
    <ResultsContext.Provider value={results}>
      <Search albums={props.albums} onSearch={search} />
      <Container>
        <Results/>
      </Container>
    </ResultsContext.Provider>
  );
};

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(json => {  
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App albums={json} />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );  
  });
```

```css
.search {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.results {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```